# Why is my function not running on a keydown event? (Native JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I am making a small table that grows as needed (not important). At first, I made it so that after the table changes, a new row would be added below. Now I want it to be so that a new row is only added after hitting `Enter`. However, when I transfer the function that controls this from it's normal event listener to a `keydown` event listener, it does not work.

**Question**: How can I get my function to work inside of a `keydown` event listener?

Edit: The events now work (after some tweaking).

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const addRowButton = document.querySelector('#addRow');

let firstNamesArray = [];
let lastNamesArray = [];
let rowNumber = 0;

function addRow() {
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let firstNameInput = document.createElement("input");
    let lastNameInput = document.createElement("input");

    firstNameInput.type = "text";
    firstNameInput.setAttribute('id', `firstName${rowNumber}`);
    cell1.appendChild(firstNameInput);
        
    lastNameInput.type = "text";
    lastNameInput.setAttribute('id', `lastName${rowNumber}`);
    cell2.appendChild(lastNameInput);

    //Works
    //lastNameInput.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);

    /* Does not work
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'Enter':
                alert("enter")
                onRowChange();
            break;
        }
    })  
    */

    //Does not work
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            alert("enter");
            onRowChange();
        }
    }, false)
}

function onRowChange(e) {
    createNames();

    if ([ ...e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children ].every(c => c.children[0].value)) {
        rowNumber++;
        addRow();
    }
}

function createNames() {
    let firstName = document.getElementById(`firstName${rowNumber}`).value;
    let lastName = document.getElementById(`lastName${rowNumber}`).value;
    firstNamesArray.push(firstName);
    lastNamesArray.push(lastName);
}

addRowButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addRow();
    addRowButton.disabled = true;
})
```

```css
table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th>
                    <th>Last Name:</th>
                </tr>
            </table> <br>

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the non-working code in the snippet so we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: You're not passing the event when you call `onRowChange()`. It should be `onRowChange(event)`

Comment: @Barmar I changed the snippet for you

Comment: Didn't you see the console error saying that it couldn't get the 'target' property of undefined?

Comment: I'm on a school Chromebook, the inspect tool is disabled so I don't have that ability, no.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to pass `event` to `onRowChange`, without that it can't access `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children`, and so it causes an error and does not add the rows. Changing your event listener to either of the following resolves the issue.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'Enter':
                console.log("enter was pressed")
                onRowChange(event);
            break;
        }
    })
```

```js
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            onRowChange(event);
        }
    }, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass event to onRowChange function like this

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
switch (event.key) {
case 'Enter':
alert("enter")
onRowChange(event);
break;
}
})